# RestAPI - how to give data in a right way

Tags: node.js, rest

I'm trying to create RestAPI. There are a lot of documents in DB, let's call those - goods. Each good have some property.

Client will get those, and show to user. Something like: ...api/goods?*filter value here*.

It looks pretty easy, but it is a wrong way to send all goods which satisfied the filter. I need to separate those, and send only needed part of data.

The first idea was create a separate route, that will obtain filter and amount documents on page, and return page count. So, front-end can build pagination and then, using handler on each pagination tab, makes requests to server, and get needed data.

I've created something like basic-example(code is not good but the main idea is): 
https://github.com/Gordienko-RU/Tiny-pagination

But I thought there are another, better implementation of it. In 'best practice' there was some note about sending pagination in header, but I couldn't figure it out.

So, I want to know, what is the best way to send data by parts, but also give to client information needed to build pagination pannel(amount of pages).

Answer (score 0):

I've found some handy method. There will be one route. Client do a request for data on first page, but answer contains not only needed data, it also will be an object with information about pagination. Something like: 
    data: [...],
    pagination: {
      pageCount: ...
      etc.
    }
Maybe not a 'best practice' but good enough)